# set collection view height after reloadData

Tags: ios

I have a collection view, by some purpose, I want to re-size the height after cells are updated dynamically. so the collection view will display all cells, no scrolling needed.

I tried two type of code,

first is normal:

```
    [self.ProjectCollectionView reloadData];
    [self.ProjectCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
    NSLog(@"setting contraint to %f from cache", weakself.ProjectCollectionView.contentSize.height);
#endif
    self.ProjectCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.ProjectCollectionView.contentSize.height;
    [self.ProjectCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
```

however the contentSize is 0:
`setting contraint to 0.000000 from cache` from cache

I tried a GCD one:

```
[self.ProjectCollectionView reloadData];
__weak typeof(HomeViewController) *weakself = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    NSLog(@"setting contraint to %f from cache", weakself.ProjectCollectionView.contentSize.height);
    weakself.ProjectCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = weakself.ProjectCollectionView.contentSize.height;
    [weakself.ProjectCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
});
```

This time, it shows `setting contraint to 410.000000 from cache`

I am confused, the first code should also be running on main thread, I add a breakpoint and use thread info to show:

```
(lldb) thread info
thread #1: tid = 0x439ee, 0x0000000106c1f411 MCompass`-[HomeViewController fetchUserModelCache](self=0x00007fd258447e50, _cmd=0x0000000106d1dd7b) + 465 at HomeViewController.m:245, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 3.1
```

Why is this different?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below function when ever you reload data

```
- (void)setCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout animated:(BOOL)animated; // transition from one layout to another
```

Comment: could you elaborate more? Simply give a func name does not help a lot. what is the order for reloadData and this func?

Comment: pass new collectionViewLayout first in collection view and reload the data , it will take new height which you have passed in setCollectionViewLayout Method

Comment: Could you please give a code demo for this and edit your answer? Thanks. That will help everyone look at your answer, not reading comments